# DLNA servers cause wireless/data to drop

Tags: 11.10, wireless, dlna

My data connection on my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop (integrated wireless) keeps freezing/dropping. I have finally narrowed down the problem. It is some how caused by DLNA servers I am running.

I have tried Serviio and PS3 Media Server. Both cause the problem. Sometimes the problem starts within seconds of transmitting data via DLNA and sometimes it could take an hour or more. I am a noob to Linux and Ubuntu. I have checked logs and really don't know what I am looking for. I see errors sometimes in the kern.log but not everytime and sometimes errors in other logs. I have to restart the OS in order to get to data/wireless to work again.

Please help, I depend greatly on a DLNA server.

The last time it did this, this is what the kern log said:

> Dec 20 04:46:13 Ubuntu-Media kernel: [ 2269.136128] phy0 ->
>   rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x06 failed for
>   offset 0x308c with error -110. Dec 20 04:47:03 Ubuntu-Media kernel: [
>   2319.136115] phy0 -> rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x07 failed for offset 0x308c with error -110. Dec 20 04:47:53
>   Ubuntu-Media kernel: [ 2369.136114] phy0 -> rt2x00usb_vendor_request:
>   Error - Vendor Request 0x06 failed for offset 0x308c with error -110.
>   Dec 20 04:48:43 Ubuntu-Media kernel: [ 2419.136125] phy0 ->
>   rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x07 failed for
>   offset 0x308c with error -110. Dec 20 04:49:33 Ubuntu-Media kernel: [
>   2469.148113] phy0 -> rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x06 failed for offset 0x308c with error -110. Dec 20 04:50:23
>   Ubuntu-Media kernel: [ 2519.196112] phy0 -> rt2x00usb_vendor_request:
>   Error - Vendor Request 0x07 failed for offset 0x308c with error -110.
>   Dec 20 04:51:13 Ubuntu-Media kernel: [ 2569.204115] phy0 ->
>   rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x06 failed for
>   offset 0x308c with error -110. Dec 20 04:52:03 Ubuntu-Media kernel: [
>   2619.224115] phy0 -> rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x07 failed for offset 0x308c with error -110. Dec 20 04:52:41
>   Ubuntu-Media kernel: [ 2656.999742] init: smbd main process (915)
>   killed by TERM signal Dec 20 04:52:41 Ubuntu-Media kernel: [
>   2657.001811] init: tty4 main process (934) killed by TERM signal Dec 20 04:52:41 Ubuntu-Media kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.

Answer (score 1):

After further research, the problem was not caused by DLNA servers, but the load the servers put on the wireless was too much because it was conflicted trying to use two drivers (rt73usb and rt2500usb). Even though I have integrated wireless it is considered usb for all practical purposes. By blacklisting rt2500usb this seems to have solved my problem. I am running Ubuntu 32 bit 11.10 on a HP Slimline S7700n w/ Athlon 64 X2 (W) 3800+ 2.0 GHz. Serviio has been running smoothly for over 3 hours now, longer than it ever has. [link to forum post that solved my problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1839033&highlight=RT73%20wireless%20usb)

Comment: I stand corrected, shortly after my post my data connection stopped working and produced the same errors in the syslog and kern.log files. Plz, could someone help me?